# Why application's name convert to lowercase

Tags: spinnaker

when create an application, the application's name of input will be `toLowerCase` (deck handle), but the name will `toUpperCase` to save the data in redis or cassandra(front50 handle), and the name will `toLowerCase` when get application.

why the application's name is save in upperCase but show in lowerCase?

the source code i saw:

front50-- com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.model.application.Application `save()`

gate-- com.netflix.spinnaker.gate.services.ApplicationService `mergeApps()`

deck-- createApplication.modal.controller.js `this.submit`

Answer (score 1):

Server groups map to internal resources for each Spinnaker cloud provider (e.g., GCE or AWS), and these resources have naming restrictions around length, capital letters, symbols, etc. A server group name in Spinnaker always starts with the application's name, which is why an application name can't contain a capital letter (and is restricted by length, symbols, etc.).